# Handle implicit `any` when iterating through embedded object keys

Tags: typescript

So here's a simplified testcase of what I'm fighting:

```
const testCase = {a:{b:"result"}}

for (const i in testCase) {
    console.log("i", i)
    for (const j in testCase[i]){
        console.log("j", j)
    }
}
```

This fails with:

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: { b: string; }; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ a: { b: string; }; }'.

5     for (const j in testCase[i]){
```

I can work around this by casting `i` as a `keyof typeof testCase`.

```
const testCase = {a:{b:"result"}}

for (const i in testCase) {
    let typedIndex = i as keyof typeof testCase
    console.log("i", i)
    for (const j in testCase[typedIndex]){
        console.log("j", j)
    }
}
```

However, this gets cumbersome depending on how many sub-ojbects I need to iterate through? Is there a better way to deal with this or am I just heading towards an anti-pattern of not having a predefined shape for `testCase`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found an answer, unless I'm explicitly setting what the keys of `testCase` are, they are by definition `any` so by changing this to use an interface like this:

```
interface TestCase {
    [prop:string]: {
        [prop:string]: string
    }
}
const testCase:TestCase = {a:{b:"result"}}
```

When I run my `for...in` loop it will know the type of the `key` being returned.

Here's the completed version:

```
interface TestCase {
    [prop:string]: {
        [prop:string]: string
    }
}
const testCase:TestCase = {a:{b:"result"}}

for (const i in testCase) {
    console.log("i", i)
    for (const j in testCase[i]){
        console.log("j", j)
    }
}
```